# What is the word or phrase describing people with food requirements?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to find a word or short phrase that generally describes *people* that have dietary requirements, food restrictions, sensitivities, and even preferences.  The phrase might apply to different kinds of restrictions, might include taste likes / dislikes, etc.

Instead of saying something like "we help people with dietary restrictions, allergies, and sensitivities" (which is verbose), is there a way to say "we help ______________" (where the blank is "people with dietary restrictions, allergies, and sensitivities")

Is there a word or short phrase that would make sense here?

Comment: Usually people are described according to their specific needs; vegan, vegetarian, lactose intolerant, gluten sensitive.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm trying to find a "looser" term / phrase that would include all of those groups.

Comment: XYZ has or needs a "special diet".  On an airplane ticket, it's "special meal".  Why classify intermediates when you can specify specifically whether the diet is celiac, nut sensitivity, kosher, halal, ovolactovegetarian, vegan, etc.

Comment: I'm sensing a generally negative or even semi-hostile response to this question.  This question comes from a _positive_ and _constructive_ position - what about it is eliciting negative responses?

Comment: I'd suggest that there is a benefit in keeping a distinction between people with *requirements* and those with *preferences*. There is a danger that if you have a catch-all phrase encompassing both that there is a tendency for people to subconsciously downgrade all of them to 'preference', which could have consequences for those with actual needs. I'd guess this may be the source of perceived antagonism in responses.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no good word** for these.

There are obviously conditions (diabetes, celiac disease, acid reflux, etc.) that limit what people can eat, but most people do not want to define themselves by their conditions, any more than they want to define themselves by gender, age, or other things that are *attributes* of a human being.

Some people can get quite militant about their food choices.  However, there too I'd suggest that their choices be treated as attributes, since this effectively denies them the opportunity for moral posturing.

There may be some *medical* term.  However, in ordinary social usage, you're probably better off with a familiar phrase, e.g. a *person with diet restrictions*.

The concept of [ableism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ableism) sometimes seems overblown, but it's not much fun being at a restaurant with nothing on the menu you can eat. There some ideas in the article you could maybe build on.

Answer (score 0):

As one who every working day in seven years has spoken to a dozen or more such people about their dietary requirements, I promise you there is no such word or phrase.

What research let you coin a term like *food requirements*, please?

Comment: I did not mean to "coin" the term, I was actually attempting to use accurate terms.  It's clear to me that I mashed-up different terms I was finding during my attempt to research this myself: food preferences, dietary requirements, food sensitivities, food allergies, etc.  _Food Requirements_ is likely not the best term.

Comment: Thanks, cale_b and why not try something you hope will work, rather than something you know won't?

In medicine, retail and cookery we talk about people with *dietary*, not *food requirements* and still, there is no collective term for the people.

The food they might eat is often *free-from…* and that's a very different idea.

Comment: Yes - agreed - I edited the question to correct this.  Just got my words tangled up.  I wonder - if this is who you work with every day, how do you describe (the "elevator pitch") what you do? That might help me understand how to articulate what I am trying to as well.

Comment: Can I, as a lay person in this context, ask you both why you are so clear that 'food requirements' is no good? Its a term I would understand and might well use myself. I would not feel that I needed to rely on research to use a general term in conversation, so why would it be wrong in a formal/business context?

Comment: @Spagirl - I didn't think it was necessarily problematic, but as Robbie clearly works in the field and had a strong reaction, I deferred.

Comment: Spagirl I, too, would understand *food requirements* and I don’t think that’s the point, any more than you think general conversation is the same as a formal/business context.

Having discussed this in some detail with dozens, if not hundreds of retailers from the most junior to managers of dozens of stores, and with thousands of consumers, over the best part of ten years, I have never once heard anyone even mention *food requirements*. My experience there is confined to England.

Comment: Cale_b, thanks for your trust… and what’s that *elevator pitch*, please? I don’t think we use that term in Britain.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin An "elevator pitch" is a "sales pitch performed in an elevator", which is basically a metaphor for giving a very concise but concrete explanation in the amount of time it takes to do an elevator ride. In your case, he's figuratively asking for a succinct explanation of your role/job.

Comment: Oh… I offer food samples in supermarkets. I've tried that on several hundred thousand people, almost none of whom has refused without a reason… which might be *I'm too busy* or, yes, *I'm allergic*.

Of the thousands who talk about it, some say they're allergic, some celiac or dairy-intolerant, diabetic or suffering from various other things… and some say they have *dietary requirements*.

My experience is that roughly 10% of people have special requirements, and I’ve never noticed anyone talking about *food requirements*; not once.

Perfectly understandable; wholly unidiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I shall probably regret this when I see how many points I lose . . .

When there is no suitable word for something, it is time to expand the English language and develop a new word.

I propose the word 'digestic'.

I cannot see any connotations to the word and nobody should be offended by it or embarrassed to say, 'I am digestic'.

There is a word 'dietetic' which is a general term meaning 'concerned with diet and nutrition'. So one could say, 'I have dietetic needs'.

Comment: Perhaps you should start a new stackexchange forum--proposals for new English-language terms?  ;-)   Personally, I think "digestic" is too similar to "digestive" or "digestif."

Comment: @Shosht I shall give that serious thought, actually. But there would probably be a flood of weird ideas to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

On airline tickets, the category term is [special meal](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/inflight/dining/special/default.aspx)

[other](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/onboard-services/special-meals.html) [major](https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/food-and-drink/special-meals) [carriers](http://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Special-meals) and [travel.se](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70916/special-meals-on-long-haul-flights)

Comment: So, 'I am a Special Eater' would alert people to my condition/preference.

Answer (score 0):

Just hosted a dinner and also had this question! Originally I was going to use "dietary restrictions" but the word restriction has a more negative connotation. In the end said "those with unique diets"; though it may detract from the medical element of some guests' diets, it's more positive and guests seemed to understand.