# Are there any words for people who exclude specific things from their diet — that aren't meat?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

The words I'm looking for would be used for a multiple choice list in a fill–out form for submitting dietary **preferences** for a dinner. I would like to refrain from pointing to allergies or dietary restrictions in the question as some people simply choose to eat a certain way rather than needing to eat that way for one reason or another.

*"Carnivore"* is often thrown around as an alternative for cases like these.

The issue with this term — in my eyes — is that it is both too exclusionary *(as people who hear "Carnivore" think of something that eats exclusively meat)* and not exclusionary enough *(as it could be defined as "something that derives its nutrition from meat." Cambridge, American Heritage, and Princeton use similarly loose definitions. These definitions do not exclude alternative sources, instead merely state what is included.)*

Is there a term for someone who excludes vegetables from their diet, but still partakes in meats, fruits, nuts, grains, tubers, et cetera? Are there terms for people who do the same with other items, for example exclude fruits, but partake in the rest?

The best solutions I have been able to come up with are compounds. I.e. *Vegetable–exclusionary* or *Fruit–exclusionary* but these terms aren't quite as clean and universally understood as, say, vegetarian and vegan. I understand that there may not be any universally understood term (as vegetarianism and veganism are culturally ubiquitous in the West, whereas that which I am looking for clearly isn't) but I figure there may be some well–defined terms which people could look up in the event they are confused about the alternatives.

Comment: Highly related: [What is the word or phrase describing people with food requirements?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/412610/191178)

Comment: Dietary restrictions: • no gluten / • no vegetables / • no meat / • no seafood / • no dairy / • no nuts / [and so on...]

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether they are dietary restrictions or preferences, but if you have an allergy you must say so clearly: allergic to nuts and nut products. Or: require gluten free meals. Or: vegan, etc. Otherwise you can just leave unliked parts of the dish uneaten. They don't really want to know if you are *picky* about your food. A friend hates green vegetables: he simply leaves them uneaten, and if you make your preferences too complicated it's sure to go wrong.

Comment: *People with restricted diets* or *people with food allergies* would be two classes of people. Terms such as vegan and pescatarian are quite recent (and not very well understood outside certain liberal circles), so I don't imagine there would be a great list of other terms for other even less common diets (maybe there might be words for people following some diets like Atkins/keto/low-carb that are more common than "no veg", but I'm not even aware of single-word terms for them).

Comment: Are you looking for a term that is derived from a word for what the diet excludes? Most of the widely used terms for such diets (e.g. *vegetarian*) are derived from the words for what the diet includes.